# Horizontal list with nested lists that display vertically

Tags: css

I'd like to display the following:

```
 <ul class="parent">
    <li>a
        <ul class="child">
            <li>a1</li>
            <li>a2</li>
            <li>a3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>b
        <ul class="child">
            <li>b1</li>
            <li>b2</li>
            <li>b3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Like this:

```
*a        *b
  *a1       *b1
  *a2       *b2
  *a3       *b3
```

I've tried a few variations of using inline and float, but can't find a way get the child menus to expand vertically and line up right using CSS.

Comment: Hi! Please remember to mark any of the answers below as accepted, if it solves! :)

Answer (score 5):

**HTML** *(fixed)*

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li>a
        <ul class="child">
            <li>a1</li>
            <li>a2</li>
            <li>a3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>b
        <ul class="child">
            <li>b1</li>
            <li>b2</li>
            <li>b3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent > li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;  
}

.child > li {
    padding-left: 20px; /* not needed if you don't reset your css */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I would avoid `float`s without `clear` when possible, I gave a try to the following CSS (same HTML, [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0cts6ooh/)):

```css
.parent > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.parent > li:before {
    font-size: 20px;
    content: '\00a0\2022\00a0\00a0';
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
    <li>a
        <ul class="child">
            <li>a1</li>
            <li>a2</li>
            <li>a3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>b
        <ul class="child">
            <li>b1</li>
            <li>b2</li>
            <li>b3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```